# My ng-table is displaying all it's values when it should only be displaying 10

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I have a calculation function that when called is to take several values and use them to fill a ng-table with the results.  Everything works fine except that the table is supposed to paginate to only show 10 values at a time.  Instead all the values are being displayed at once.  At the bottom of the page the next and back buttons appear for shifting through the table's values.  Below is the angularjs code I am using.  I am not sure where the problem is.

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,        //show first page
        count: 10       //conunt per page
    },{
        total: $scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.length,
            getData: function($defer, params){
                $defer.resolve($scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }

    });

    //populates the Subsidy table
    $scope.populateSubsidyTable = function(monthlySubsidyRedAm, startingSubsidy, monthsOnSubsidy)
    {
        var currentSubsidy = 0;
        var currentDate = $scope.startingDate;
        var subsidyDate = new Date();
        var monthsLeft = monthsOnSubsidy
        $scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable = [];
        var subsidyPaymentScheduleArray = [];

        if(startingSubsidy > 1)
        {
            currentSubsidy = startingSubsidy;
        }

        if(monthlySubsidyRedAm <=0)
        {
            totalAmount = currentSubsidy * 6;
        }
        else
        {
            //the first month

            $scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.push({
                    subsidyDate: currentDate,
                    subsidyAmount: currentSubsidy
            });

            $scope.totalSubsidy = $scope.totalSubsidy + currentSubsidy;

            //the first 5 months after the first
            for(i=2; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1,'months').format("MM/DD/YYYY");


                $scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.push({
                    subsidyDate: currentDate,
                    subsidyAmount: currentSubsidy
                });

                monthsLeft = monthsOnSubsidy - 6;

                $scope.totalSubsidy = $scope.totalSubsidy + currentSubsidy;

            }
            //the rest of the subsidies
            while(monthsOnSubsidy > 0)
            {
                if((currentSubsidy - monthlySubsidyRedAm) > 1)
                {
                        currentSubsidy = currentSubsidy - monthlySubsidyRedAm;

                        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1,'months').format("MM/DD/YYYY");

                        $scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.push({
                            subsidyDate: currentDate,
                            subsidyAmount: currentSubsidy
                        });

                        $scope.totalSubsidy = $scope.totalSubsidy + currentSubsidy;

                        monthsLeft--;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            //reload subsidy table
            $scope.tableParams.total($scope.subsidyPaymentScheduleTable.length);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        }
    }
```

this is the html code

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table subsidyPaymentScheduleTable">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="subsidy in subsidyPaymentScheduleTable" class="clickableRow">
            <td data-title="'Date'">
                {{subsidy.subsidyDate}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Amount'">
                {{subsidy.subsidyAmount | currency:"$"}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when I declare variables under `$scope`, rather as `var data = [];`, That ng-table doesn't seem to see them correctly.